# SSIS Execute Process Task with Python- Exit code was "1"

Tags: python, ssis

I am trying to run a Python script from the SSIS Execute Process Task. I am getting the following error. I've tried looking around stackoverflow, but cannot seem to find a suitable answer to my problem.

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\Q300L\source\repos\TestScript\Package.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC0029151 at Execute Process Task, Execute Process Task: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe" "C:\Users\Q300L\Desktop\GGTT.py" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
Task failed: Execute Process Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\Q300L\source\repos\TestScript\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Process details.

[image]

My Python script is a simple web scraping that takes the SPY companies from a wikipedia table.

```
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')

My_table = soup.find('table', attrs={"id":"constituents"})

counter_ = 0

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["symbol", "security", "SEC_fillings", "GICS_Sector", "Headquarters_Location", "Date_first_added", "CIK", "Founded"])

for tr in My_table.find_all('tr'):
    counter_ += 1
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    if not tds:
        continue
    tmp_list = []
    for td in tds[:8]:
        tmp_list.append(td.text.strip())
    df.loc[counter_] = tmp_list

df.to_csv("C:/Users/Q300L/Desktop/Rich/Staging/SPY.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

But the code gives me the error mentioned above. The code runs fine in both IDLE and Visual Studio Code. And succesfully creates a file with the scraped data.

I did try run a more simple task of creating a file with SSIS Execute Process Task, to get a minimum viable product up and running. The below code runs just fine, when executing my SSIS package:

```
import csv
with open('C:/Users/Q300L/Desktop/innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "Linux Kernel"])
    writer.writerow([2, "Tim Berners-Lee", "World Wide Web"])
    writer.writerow([3, "Guido van Rossum", "Python Programming"])
```

I also tried to make a simple python script with `import csv` and nothing else. Which runs fine, when I then add the next `import requests` it starts to complain, and throws the same error.

I'm hoping some may point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: in a minimal script, import sys and send sys.path to a log file.   check that they match.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running manually your python files with the same interpreter used in the executable process property?
Be sure the interpreter you are indicating in the executable process property has that library (requests) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the property FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue to false.

I too got similar error and python program was to print hello world. By changing above property the error resolved. Hope this will help.